# Most elegant way to have one HTML element mirror another?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have two HTML elements that should always contain the same inner HTML text, what is the most elegant way to update them both at the same time?

For example:

```
<head>
    <title id="pageTitle">My Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="screenTitle">My Application</h1>
</body>
```

I would like the innerHTML of screenTitle and pageTitle to remain identical whenever a JavaScript function changes one of them.

I know I can iterate through the pageTitle and screenTitle elements, updating each of them whenever I change the string "My Application", but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: How are they being modified from a JavaScript function? Couldn't you add additional code to grab the innerHTML from `pageTitle` and set that to the `screenTitle` identifier.

Comment: The elements are being modified by an AJAX onreadystatechange handler function.  The function receives a JSON object containing the request to update the page's title.  I know I can iterate through each of the elements in JavaScript and update them, but it seems like a very "hard-coded" approach.

Comment: I actually think that updating both with js is enough elegant to do it.
document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML = update;
document.getElementById("screenTitle").innerHTML = update;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.title.innerHTML` is read-only in IE. This supposed to be a cross-browser method:

```
document.getElementById('screenTitle').innerHTML = document.title = 'My Application';
```

Instead of a literal value you can use a variable ofcourse.

If you really need something "elegant" (=== exotic), you can use a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set):

```
var page = {
    set title(text) {
        document.getElementById('screenTitle').innerHTML = document.title = text;
    }
};
```

When ever you need to change the titles, just set it: `page.title = newTitle;`. Only you need to care of, is that you can refer `page` object from the current scope. Also this will only work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single function that encapsulates writes to both elements. So instead of directly using DOM methods, the rest of your code would use a function such as:

```
function setTitle(newTitle)
{
    document.getElementById('pageTitle').innerHTML = newTitle;
    document.getElementById('screenTitle').innerHTML = newTitle;
}
```

Of course this could be optimized/DRYed/refactored/overengineered ad nauseam...

```
function setTitle(newTitle)
{
    if (setTitle.elements)
    {
        var id = document.getElementByIdl
        setTitle.elements = [id('pageTitle'), id('screenTitle')];
    }

    setTitle.elements.forEach(function (elt)
    {
        elt.innerHTML = newTitle;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a JS method that updates both simultaneously as long as you are in control of all the code that is going to modify the elements. Something like:

```
function updateElementGroup( newInnerHTML ) {
    document.getElementById( 'pageTitle' ).innerHTML = newInnerHTML;
    document.getElementById( 'screenTitle' ).innerHTML = newInnerHTM;
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
updateElementGroup( 'New Text' );
```

If you are not in control of all the code you could set up some listeners to catch whenever one is changed and update the other one accordingly, something like this:

```
var isUpdating = false;
var elements = [
    document.getElementById( 'pageTitle' ),
    document.getElementById( 'screenTitle' ),
];

for ( i in elements ) {
    elements[i].addEventListener( 'DOMCharacterDataModified', function( evt ) {
        if ( isUpdating ) {
            return;
        }

        isUpdating = true;

        for ( i in elements ) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = evt.newValue;
        }

        isUpdating = false;
    } );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#pageTitle').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if ($('#pageTitle').html() != $('#screenTitle').html())
        $('#screenTitle').html($('#pageTitle').html());
});

$('#screenTitle').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if ($('#pageTitle').html() != $('#screenTitle').html())
        $('#pageTitle').html($('#screenTitle').html());
});
```

Comment: The author didn't say they were using JQuery.