# Javascript variable not updating its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I set the following in my console:

```
document.getElementById('messsages').textContent;
```

which gave me the output `"this is a message i sent through websocket chat!"`

I then did

```
var convo = document.getElementById('messsages').textContent;
```

and typed in `convo` into the console and it gave me the same output as before. I then sent another message through my websocket chat and typed in convo and it gave me the old output but when I typed in `document.getElementById('messsages').textContent;` it gave me the new output.

Why is this? And is there a method for me to assign a variable which updates its value accordingly with my element?

Comment: No, there isn't, since everything in JS is passed by value. Instead you could use an object with getter/setter properties.

Comment: Hey Teemu, can you provide an example of such an object?

Comment: [At this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15055679/1169519) there's a setter, a getter would be just a function returning `document.getElementById('messsages').textContent` in your case.

Comment: So basically if I paste the following in my code, then 'convo' will always equal to the current value of  the div 'messsages' which contains dynamic content? :  `var convo = {
    set title(text) {
        document.getElementById('messsages').textContent = document.title = text;
    }
};`

Comment: @StackOverQuestions Ofcourse not, you've to apply your own code to the setter structure. The linked page shows a concept of setter only, it's not a direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
var convo = function convo() {
                return (function(elem) { 
                    return elem.textContent 
                }(document.getElementById("messages"))
            };
```

See also [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
setInterval(function() {
 var arr = "abcdefg".split("");
 var i = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length -1);
 document.getElementById("messages").textContent = arr[i];
}, 2000);

var convo = function convo() {
  return (function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent
  }(document.getElementById("messages")))
};

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(convo())
});
```

```html
click
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: Hey it didn't work, I get the error in the console "convo is not defined".

Comment: @StackOverQuestions If possible , can post pieces tried at OP ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle to demonstrate ?